# How to create a batch id in Spark's custom Receiver?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to identify the batch in custom receivers. Each receiver should have the same id for the duration of batch interval.

I try to have a timer in each receiver and start value for first batch. Then I set the timer to update the id after batch interval. This can work for some time. However, if any receiver fails, then the synchronization is broken. Is there any way to get the exact batch time or event in receivers?

Can I use broadcast variables to synchronize them?

I expect to have exactly same batch id in each receiver. It does not matter that id is integer or string or something else.